# Magento 1.9 - Get all products that contain upsell

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

how I can get all products that have / contain upsell products.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <?php
    $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('id');
    foreach ($_products as $product){
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
     if (count($_product->getUpSellProductIds()) > 0) :

echo $_product->getName()." has upsell products.";
   endif; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, can you tell me please what is the way to check if the product contain one of this: Upsell, Crosel and Related?

Comment: You can use getUpSellProductIds() function from product model to get all upsell product ids.

Comment: $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(-YOURPRODUCTID--);$upprods = $_product->getUpSellProductIds();print_r($upprods);

Comment: and what is the product ID? I need to check all products if there is any product that have one of this: Upsell, Crosel and Related, so there is not exist any product ID

Comment: You can get all product collection from this:
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();

foreach ($_productCollection as $prd)
{
echo $prd->getId();
}

Comment: I see, the code that is in your answer is not work, return blank page

Comment: Ok I have created one code also tested it with my demo magento store please check another answer below.

Comment: both codes come with the blank page, so let me explain you again maybe you not understand well what I need ... I want to check all my products if there is any upsell ... If one product will contain upsell products then display sku of that product